# How can you complete an interrupted Debian installation?

Tags: linux, debian

I started a Debian installation on a dual boot with Windows, but the package updating procedure got interrupted. Now I have only a text console available. How can I continue the Debian installation?

I also do not have a network connection, I need to connect to a wireless device, but how? The wireless network does not need any key to connect to...

Answer (score 1):

I think you'd have to redo the installation completely from scratch. Any type of resume would be fraught with potential problems going forward, IMO.

I did find this thread which is a bit dated from 2006 that discusses this very issue, but it assumed you had internet access which you indicated you did not.

- [Resuming interrupted etch beta Installation over Internet](http://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2006/01/msg01386.html)

That thread discusses using `base-config` to continue an interrupted installation from the console, but I don't see how this could be used by you without internet access.

Comment: I whish you suggested something else. But maybe this is the onlzy way... thanks

Comment: @Alex - see update.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly note that this might not go as planed.

To connect to an access point from a command line you can use these standard tools that should be present.
You can get information about them by tiping "man nameoftool".
Afaik some of these need to be run as root so "sudo".

```
iwconfig
```

should give you an "wlan0" with some information about it
so you know it's module is loaded and it is usable

```
ifconfig wlan0 up
```

to turn it on

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid nameofyourap
```

to set it up

Now you have a connection to your AP.
You still need to give it a IP address.

```
dhcpcd wlan0
```

sets up the connection as a dhcp client
meaning it gets an IP and DNS address from the access point

If there is no "dhcpcd", you can try dhclient instead.
Of course this is all basic so it would be simple, but it should work in your case.
To test try "ping www.google.com".

Then you can try fixing the system.
What slm wrote has probably more chance to work.
I don't normally use debian so this is all i came up with.

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

where the "-f" flag means fix

More about apt-get options you can get from "man apt-get".